# Taylor polynomial and error estimation

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, taylor-expansion

I want to find an approximation for $ \sqrt[3]{x} $ and an estimate for the absolute error made in that approximation. For this, the exercise asked us to approximate the function by a first degree Taylor polynomial at a = 64. I did it this way:
$$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x} \rightarrow f(64)=4$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}} \rightarrow f'(64)=\frac{1}{48}$$
$$f''(x)=\bigg(\frac{1}{3}\bigg)\bigg(-\frac{2}{3}\bigg)x^{-\frac{5}{3}}=\bigg(-\frac{2}{9}\bigg)x^{-\frac{5}{3}}$$

Lagrange rest:

$$\frac{f''(c)}{2!}(c-64)^2$$

Taylor polynomial:

$$f(x)\approx 4+\frac{x-64}{48}$$

Then I tried to estimate the error using the rest of Lagrange:
$$65\approx 64$$
$$f(65)\approx 4+\frac{1}{48}$$
$$|f(x)-p_1(x)|=|r_2(x)|=\bigg|\frac{1}{3}\bigg(-\frac{2}{3}\bigg)\frac{c^{-\frac{5}{3}}}{2!}(c-64)^2\bigg|=-\frac{2}{9}\frac{c^{-\frac{5}{3}}}{2!}|c-64|^2$$

As 64 to 65 differ in one unit, $|c-64|^2\leq1$:
$$|f(x)-p_1(x)|\leq -\frac{2}{9}\frac{1}{2c^{\frac{5}{3}}}\leq -\frac{2}{9}\frac{1}{2\times 64^{\frac{5}{3}}}$$

My question is: In the last step I replace $c$ with 64, but I don't know if I should replace $c$ with 64 or 65. I would like to know why the value should replace $c$ and if my resolution is correct and complete, if it were possible.

Comment: First, in $r_2$ it should be $(65-64)^2$ instead of $(c-64)^2$, see for example Rudin's book page 111. Now to estimate $r_2$, one takes the worse bound, i.e. consider the $c$ that makes $r_2$ biggest. So in this example we estimate the error by taking $c=64$.